# using entity framework in classlibrary

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am having problem in referencing entity framework 6 in my class library project. The project is registred for com interop. I have post build event like

> SET GACUTIL="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\gacutil.exe" SET
>   REGASM="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe"
>
> %REGASM% /u  $(TargetFileName) /tlb:ClassLibrary1.tlb %GACUTIL% /u
>   $(TargetFileName)
>
> %REGASM% $(TargetFileName) /tlb:ClassLibrary1.tlb %GACUTIL% /i
>   $(TargetFileName)
>
> %REGASM% $(TargetFileName) /tlb:ClassLibrary1.tlb %GACUTIL% /i
>   $(TargetFileName)

whenever I build I get error:

**Cannot register assembly: "myassembly" Could not load file or assembly 'Entity Framework , Version 6.0.0.0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you didn't add entity framework assembly to your class library. Use the nuget console to install it: 
`PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.0.0`

https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/6.0.0

Comment: Yes I have referenced it via nuget but still errors occure